# Sacar de una bd, cual es el usuario que más publica

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo estadisticas en un panel de administración además de mostrar otros datos. Y pense en sacar a modo de información cual es el usuario que más noticias a publicado, pero no se como generar esa consulta si es que se puede hacer.

Tabla noticias:

```
idNoticia
imagen
titulo
subtitulo
cuerpo
idUs         <- aqui sale el usuario
idCategoria
fecha
estado
visitas
```

En `idUs`se registra el usuario que publica la noticia.

¿Hay posibilidad de hacer una cosulta que me saque cual aparece más en la tabla?

Saludos

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106334/discussion-on-question-by-miguel-sacar-de-una-bd-cual-es-el-usuario-que-mas-pub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El query seria:

Editado: Prueba con esto ya con tus campos y tablas.

```
select consulta.idUs 
from (select idUs,count(idUs) NoticiasPorUsuario 
             from noticia group by idUs) as consulta 
order by consulta.NoticiasPorUsuario desc  LIMIT 1
```

NOTA: no se si el ejemplo que pongo aplique o lo puedas replicar en MySQL, una disculpa por eso.  Mi ejemplo es para SQL Server.

Hice un pequeño ejemplo, espero que con esto puedas resolver tu problema y aprender algo, no se si sea la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero es la solución que se me ocurre. saludos.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#users') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #users
GO
CREATE TABLE #users (
    idUser int IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key,
    nombre nvarchar(max)
);

insert into #users select 'A'
insert into #users select 'B'
insert into #users select 'C'

select * from #users

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#noticias') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #noticias
GO
CREATE TABLE #noticias (
    idNoticia int IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key,
    idUser int,
    noticia nvarchar(max),
);

insert into #noticias select 1,'N1'
insert into #noticias select 1,'N2'
insert into #noticias select 1,'N3'
insert into #noticias select 3,'N4'
insert into #noticias select 3,'N5'
insert into #noticias select 1,'N6'
insert into #noticias select 2,'N7'
insert into #noticias select 2,'N8'
insert into #noticias select 2,'N9'

select * from #noticias

--Este query agrupa por usuario y cuenta las noticias por usuario
select idUser,count(idUser) NoticiasPorUsuario from #noticias group by idUser

--Para saber que usuario tiene mas noticias:
-- puedes poner los datos ordenados de mayor a menor y tomar el top 1 idUsuario
select top 1 consulta.idUser UsuarioConMasNoticias from
(select idUser,count(idUser) NoticiasPorUsuario from #noticias group by idUser) as consulta
order by consulta.NoticiasPorUsuario desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106335/discussion-on-answer-by-cristina-carrasco-sacar-de-una-bd-cual-es-el-usuario-qu).

Comment: Cristina no se entiende cual es larespuesta....

Comment: La respuesta es el query, pero el OP pregunto mas cosas porque es muy novato, que sugieres que añada en la respuesta? puedes editarla para que se entienda de mejor manera.

Comment: No hay pregunta para todo el resto. Deberia haber hecho otra pregunta. Tambien borra la parte de sql server porque no funciona en mysql sobre lo que es la pregunta. Todo esto, mas los 20000 comentarios, quedo hecho un lio... hasta me hizo confundir y borre tu respuesta :p (que luego recupere, obviamente!)

Comment: Bueno, no se bien como usar el chat... y segunda lo miso le sugeri al OP, que abriera otra pregunta.  Pero creo que tampoco sabe mucho como usar stack, te agradezco por tu ayuda.

Comment: el chat es un chat comun y corriente.. ingresa por [chat] y listo! ese usuario tambien podia usar el chat.

Answer (score 0):

Tras la respuesta de @Franco fernandez:

**Consulta:**

```
          $maxNoticias = $mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(Total) 
                     FROM (SELECT COUNT(idUs) AS Total FROM noticias) AS Results");
                     if($mx = $maxNoticias->fetch_array()){}
```

**Imprimirlo en pantalla:**

```
Noticias publicadas: <span><?php echo $mx['Results']; ?></span>
```

Pero no funciona, se me queda blanca la pantalla

EDITO:

Tenia que ser `noticia` no `noticias` --> ahora carga la pantalla pero no los resultados de cuanta cantidad.

Puedes probar con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MAX(counted) FROM
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
   FROM noticia
) AS counts;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106336/discussion-on-answer-by-miguel-sacar-de-una-bd-cual-es-el-usuario-que-mas-publi).

Comment: Esto es una respuesta, otra pregunta o que es?

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Simule en PHPMYADMIN tu base de datos en sql y obtuve el resultado correcto realizando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MAX( counted )
 FROM (SELECT COUNT( idNoticia), idUs 
 AS counted
 FROM noticia) AS counts
```

Lo que obtuve de esta manera es el 'id' del usuario con mayores noticias publicadas, cabe destacar que tendrías que hacer un 'inner join' con la tabla user si quieres obtener el 'name' del mismo en vez del 'id'.

NOTA: la consulta que yo use fue otra porque tenia otros nombres en la base pero era el mismo formato. Acá en la respuesta te la copie como deberías realizarla vos para que te funcione con tu base de datos.

Comment: Se me queda en blanco no entiendo nada

Comment: que tipo de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: estoy utilizando mysql

Comment: De este modo `$maxNoticias = $mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(counted) FROM (SELECT COUNT(idNoticia), idUs AS counted FROM noticia) AS counts");
                     if($mxa = $maxNoticias->fetch_array()){}`

Comment: prueba de tirar la consulta sola en tu administrador de base de datos, no desde el código como lo estas haciendo

Comment: Me dice esto: `No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list sidebar`  No se si tiene algo que ver o bien es del programa, utilizo MySQL Workbench

Comment: Este es el error @franco fernandez , `Errormessage: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'apolo2019.noticia.idUs'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Los metodos de agregacion en SQL no se pueden utlizar sin group by.  Ejemplo MAX, MIN, COUNT.. etc

Comment: `SELECT MAX( counted )
 FROM (SELECT COUNT( idNoticia), idUs 
 AS counted
 FROM noticia group by idUs) AS counts`  <-- esa seria la solucion que es basicamente la misma respuesta que yo estoy dando XD

Comment: Claro como dice @CristinaCarrasco, solo le faltaba el group by a mi query

Comment: Exacto, en realidad es un query bastante simple...  :S  ya deberías poderlo solucionar @Miguel

Comment: mmmm ahora no me da error pero no imprime nada. Lo imprimo así, `<?php echo $res['counts']; ?>` es correcto?